# Usar this para eliminar a un elemento del div

Tags: jquery

*El detalle esta, cuando le doy click a ( xClones ) = se eliminan todos los elementos de #campoBusq y la pregunta es como se hace para que se elimine solo el elemento que se le de el click*

```
<div id="campoBusq">
         <div class="elemento">
             texto1 <div class="xClones"> X </div> 
         </div>

         <div class="elemento">
             texto2 <div class="xClones"> X </div>
          </div>

         <div class="elemento">
             texto3 <div class="xClones"> X </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

> ```
> $('#campoBusq').on('click','.xClones',function() {
>    $("#campoBusq").find(".elemento").remove();*Como podria usar un this aqui*
>
> });
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguro que no te funciona así?

```
$('#campoBusq').on('click','.xClones',function() {
     $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: sorry, si funciona

Comment: Pues si te estoy diciendo e.e Lo mismo te dije en tu pregunta pasada ¬¬

Comment: gracias amigo, ahora si complete el codigo vere que se presenta mas adelante :-)

Comment: Y pones la respuesta de Gustavo como la correcta XD! Bueno, equis. El fin de semana estoy ausente, la semana que viene te sigo ayudando, byte.

Comment: gracias bay men

Comment: @user2930137 ¿reclamas para que marquen tu respuesta cuando es lo mismo que la mía y que @Jorius? Reclama cuando escribas una respuesta que se distinga en calidad de otras respuestas.

Comment: @Gustavo García tu respuesta no era la misma que la mía. Yo puse la respuesta con patern, que era lo que él realmente necesitaba pues le he estado dando seguimiento a su caso y esa respuesta yo se la había puesto como comentario en una pregunta pasada. Tu respuesta no era lo que necesitaba, cuando viste mi respuesta editaste la tuya agregando la mía a la tuya :). Mi respuesta soluciona el problema que tiene el que pregunta, como siempre.

Comment: ¿En qué te basas para decir que "vi la tuya" y me copié? Simplemente estoy en el cliente móvil y se dificulta la visión del código. ¿Crees que un usuario con mi reputación iría copiando respuestas? :facepalm:

Comment: Ah.............

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo se hace para que se elimine **solo el elemento que se le de el click**?

Simple y llanamente con `remove`:

```
$(this).remove();
```

O si quieres eliminar el padre (`.elemento`):

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Comment: no funciona, pero no quiero decir que no funcione el tuyo

Comment: Este codio   $("#campoBusq").find(".elemento").remove(); me sirve pero el problema es que me elimina a todos con el nombre  de clase elemento

Comment: @Gamez ¿No ves que mi código es lo mismo que lo que te han respondido los demás? ¿En qué te basas para decir "no funciona"?

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente utiliza `parent();` y dale el nombre del *elemento* de la siguiente forma:

```js
$('#campoBusq').on('click', '.xClones', function() {
  $(this).parent("div").remove();
});
```

```css
*{
 font-family: Arial;
}

#campoBusq{
  width: 60px;
}

.xClones{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campoBusq">
  <div class="elemento">
    texto1
    <div class="xClones"> X </div>
  </div>

  <div class="elemento">
    texto2
    <div class="xClones"> X </div>
  </div>

  <div class="elemento">
    texto3
    <div class="xClones"> X </div>
  </div>
</div>
```